# how to host mysql database with asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have developed an asp.net website which is displaying image from mysql database.I have used here mysql connector version 5.* to connect to mysql database server.i created table from command line of mysql,but when i host this application on windows server,i can just create a database on the windows server from plesk panel.but how can i create the table over there?...can you give me any guidelines?I can create table from C# using the tablebuilder,but it supports the latest version of mysql connector,but i am not sure whether hosting server will support it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.freehostingtutorials.com/windows-based-hosting-accounts-knowledgebase/how-to-create-table-in-my-sql-databse-in-plesk-control-panel/

You can create tables from within Plesk Control Panel, just follow the guide above to see how.

I've done it before and it's quite painless.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this page, it is in Arabic but it has enough images to deal it with plesk:
http://libyanspider.com/arabic/m/knowledgebase/95/-----PhpMyAdmin-or-Aspnet-Enterprise-Manager.html

Comment: it is displaying only how to create database on plesk panel,that i used to ..but I need to know how can i create table inside this database.

Comment: @suhail Well look at the last image (second image indeed) at the right hand side of it you will see pointer cursor surrounded by red square. this is the place by clicking it you will create tables and interact with data.